# Image. textfield and textarea in buildForm for every domain language in Symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

Okay, another issue. It's a bit hard to explain so sorry in advance.

I have an entity called `SlideContent`, which basically stores the `id`, the `slide` (relation to an entity called `SlideshowSlide`), `language` (relation to an entity called `Language`), `title` and `content`.

I also have an entity called `Domain`. This has an relation to `Language` as well (as every `Domain` has one language).

Every `User` can have one or more `Domain`s they have rights on. If you have rights on a `Domain`, you obviously have auto rights for the `Language` of that `Domain`.

Now, what I need to do is, add a `tr` in a `table` for every `Language` the `User` has rights on. In that `tr`, it needs to display the `base64img` from `Language` as an image, an input field for the title and a textarea for the content. I prefer to have it in a form class.

I tried the following:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    foreach ($options['user']->getDomains() as $domain)
    {
        $builder->add('titles[' . $domain->getLanguage()->getId() . ']', TextType::class);
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'user' => null
    ));
}
```

But I get the following error:

`The name "titles[2]" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").`

Is it possible to do what I want? I know I probably have to do one more foreach in my template for the `base64img` and for adding everything in a `tr`, but how can I achieve what I want in terms of the indexed array input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach is okay in principle, but the name of a field may only contain the mentioned characters (see your error message). (One simple apparent reason is, that this method probably avoids naming conflicts)

to circumvent this but to write it into the result data object/array you can do this:

```
foreach ($options['user']->getDomains() as $domain)
{
    $builder->add('titles_' . $domain->getLanguage()->getId(), TextType::class, [
         'property_path' => 'titles['.$domain->getLanguage()->getId().']',
    ]);
}
```

see [`property_path` option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) for more details.

so essentially: make the form field names valid, and still get the same property paths you would have gotten otherwise.

if access is needed in template:

```
form['titles_'~language.id]
```

(depending on how your form is named and the language variable)

Comment: That works but now I get `Neither the property "titles" nor one of the methods "titles()", "gettitles()"/"istitles()"/"hastitles()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".` (I use `{{ form_row(contentForm.titles[language.id]) }}` in my loop. How do I successfully get one title field?

Comment: `form_row(contentForm['titles_'~language.id])` should work.